# Recycerview display specific data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have 2 types of users. the first user can see all the data at recycler view. the second user only can see specific data at recycler view.

Right now I only able to display the specific data, once the second user clicked, it will display the first data, not according to the position.

How to fix user clicks at the right display and will proceed at the right data?

MainActivity.java. Preparing to display a recycler view according to condition.

```
private void prepareMainMenu(final String type) {
        MainItem mainItem;
        switch (type) {
            case "Customer":
                mainItem = new MainItem("Customer", imageViewMain[1]);
                mainItemList.add(mainItem);
                break;
            case "Packages":
                mainItem = new MainItem("Packages", imageViewMain[2]);
                mainItemList.add(mainItem);
                break;
            case "Live Chat":
                mainItem = new MainItem("Live Chat", imageViewMain[3]);
                mainItemList.add(mainItem);

                break;
            case "Transaction":
                mainItem = new MainItem("Transaction", imageViewMain[5]);
                mainItemList.add(mainItem);

                break;
            case "Profit Report":
                mainItem = new MainItem("Profit Report", imageViewMain[4]);
                mainItemList.add(mainItem);

                break;
            case "Owner":
                mainItem = new MainItem("Admin", imageViewMain[0]);
                mainItemList.add(mainItem);

                mainItem = new MainItem("Customer", imageViewMain[1]);
                mainItemList.add(mainItem);

                mainItem = new MainItem("Packages", imageViewMain[2]);
                mainItemList.add(mainItem);

                mainItem = new MainItem("Live Chat", imageViewMain[3]);
                mainItemList.add(mainItem);

                mainItem = new MainItem("Profit Report", imageViewMain[4]);
                mainItemList.add(mainItem);

                mainItem = new MainItem("Transaction", imageViewMain[5]);
                mainItemList.add(mainItem);
                break;

        }
        //Display
        mainViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

MainViewAdapter.java (where the user will click)

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        MainItem mainItem = mainItemList.get(position);
        holder.getTextViewTitle().setText(mainItem.getNameMain());

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(mainItem.getImageMain())
                .into(holder.imageViewMain);

        holder.getView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Check the position
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, AdminActivity.class));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, CustomerActivity.class));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, PackagesSelectorActivity.class));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, LiveChatActivity.class));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ProfitReportActivity.class));
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, TransactionActivity.class));
                        break;
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

UPDATED:
This is where the method prepareMainMenu goes.

```
 private void retrieveData() {
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            databaseReference.child("admin").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        Admin admin = dataSnapshot.getValue(Admin.class);
                        if (admin != null) {
                            fullName = admin.getFullName();
                            email = admin.getEmail();
                            type = admin.getType();

                            //Then display
                            textViewFullName.setText(fullName);
                            textViewEmail.setText(email);
                            textViewType.setText(type);
                            //Check the type of admin
                            switch (type) {
                                case "Customer":
                                    prepareMainMenu("Customer");
                                    break;
                                case "Packages":
                                    prepareMainMenu("Packages");
                                    break;
                                case "Live Chat":
                                    prepareMainMenu("Live Chat");
                                    break;
                                case "Transaction":
                                    prepareMainMenu("Transaction");
                                    break;
                                case "Profit Report":
                                    prepareMainMenu("Profit Report");
                                    break;
                                case "Owner":
                                    prepareMainMenu("Owner");
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you passing the user type to your adapter?

Comment: @shb yess.. im passing them

Comment: then check the type of your user before starting an activity. I don't see any issues yet

Comment: @shb I display the recycler view according to user type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the **position** inside `onBindViewHolder` use the mainItem name to differentiate click event.

```
holder.getView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (mainItem.getNameMain().toLowerCase()) {
        case "admin":
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, AdminActivity.class));
            break;
        case "customer":
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, CustomerActivity.class));
            break;
        case "packages":
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, PackagesSelectorActivity.class));
            break;
        case "live chat":
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, LiveChatActivity.class));
            break;
        case "profit report":
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ProfitReportActivity.class));
            break;
        case "transaction":
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, TransactionActivity.class));
            break;
    }

}
});
```

Also, I have used lower case string comparison which will reduce the risk of string matching.

Comment: the risk of string matching? which is our side or their side. what I mean is risk for me?

Comment: actually nothing. just to validate which item is clicked in the switch case

Comment: ty so much sir!

Answer (score 0):

if you look at this recycler from any user role perspective you will find the data is filtered according to the current logged-in role.
so you easily add the user role into MainItem class as a property for any object created from this class. 
and in prepareMainMenu function, you can easily filter the data according to  the current logged-in role

first, you can define an Enum for different roles

```
public enum Roles {
    CustomerRole, AdminRole
}
```

then pass this role as property to MainItem class like this

```
MainItem("Customer", imageViewMain[1],Roles.Customer);
```

And onBindView Method will be like this

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        MainItem mainItem = mainItemList.get(position);
        holder.getTextViewTitle().setText(mainItem.getNameMain());

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(mainItem.getImageMain())
                .into(holder.imageViewMain);

        holder.getView().setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

              switch (mainItem.role) {
                 case Roles.CustomerRole: 
                      context.startActivity(new Intent(context, CustomerActivity.class));
                      break;

                 case Roles.Admin: 
                      context.startActivity(new Intent(context, AdminActivity.class));
                      break;
            }
        });
    }
```

and another solution that looks much better is to pass the class name to your dto like this

```
class MainItem {
    String title;
    String image;
    Class className;

    public MainItem(String title, String image, Class className) {
        this.title = title;
        this.image = image;
        this.className = className;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public Class getClassName() {
        return className;
    }
}
```

and the creation of your data will be

```
MainItem("Customer", imageViewMain[1],CustomerActivity.class);
```

and your onBindView method will be like this

```
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            MainItem mainItem = mainItemList.get(position);
            holder.getTextViewTitle().setText(mainItem.getNameMain());

            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(mainItem.getImageMain())
                    .into(holder.imageViewMain);

            holder.getView().setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   context.startActivity(new Intent(context, mainItem.getClassName));

            });
        }
```

Comment: it would be ok if you prepare with answer

Comment: The situation is when I click item in recycler view [2] . and then next activity, it will display activity item recycler view for [0].

Comment: @Ticherhaz I don't understand what you say

Comment: can we teamviewer?

Comment: Yes. Just forward in the model type of user and based on that in adapter show needed info

Comment: @BorisRuzanov I still cannot figure it out.